# Concerned with replicate fn in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using following query

```
create table  #Attendence (id int identity(1,1),det varchar(2000))
insert into #Attendence (det )
select  --convert(char(10),@Date,3) +REPLICATE(' ', 20 - LEN(convert(char(10),@Date,3)))+
        staff.StaffNAme +REPLICATE(' ', 20 - LEN(staff.StaffNAme ))+
        case Att.FN when 1 then 'Present'
                else 'Absent'
        end  +REPLICATE(' ', 20 - LEN(case Att.FN when 1 then 'Present'
                else 'Absent'
        end ))+
        case Att.AN when 1 then 'Present'
                else 'Absent'
        end +REPLICATE(' ', 20 - LEN(case Att.AN when 1 then 'Present'
                else 'Absent'
        end  ))
from  Staff_Details staff
      inner join
        STAFF_Attendance att
            on staff.staffid=att.staffId
Select * from   #Attendence
```

The problem is in the resultset as the length of STaffName increases, the values in the right of staffname is moving rightward.Can anybody help to make each column fixed length?

Answer (score 2):

```
create table  #Attendence (id int identity(1,1),det varchar(2000))
insert into #Attendence (det )
select  --cast(convert(char(10),@Date,3) as char(20)) +
        cast(staff.StaffNAme as char(20)) +
        cast(case Att.FN when 1 then 'Present' else 'Absent' end as char(20)) +
        cast(case Att.AN when 1 then 'Present' else 'Absent' end as char(20))
from  Staff_Details staff
      inner join
        STAFF_Attendance att
            on staff.staffid=att.staffId
Select * from   #Attendence
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Staffname has trailing spaces.
These will be ignored by LEN.

Try this to force a length of 20 chars exactly:

```
LEFT(staff.StaffNAme + '                    ', 20)
```

...instead of...

```
staff.StaffNAme + REPLICATE(' ', 20 - LEN(staff.StaffNAme))
```

Comment: still the same result.Is there another way?

Comment: @ramyatk06: we'll need some more info then: sample data, wrong and correct outputs etc. My LEFT code will give exactly 20 characters.

Comment: Another way to do the same would be to `cast(staff.StaffNAme as char(20))`.

Comment: @Andriy M: doh! its obvious now. You should make that an answer

Comment: Hey, I've just noticed it was an old question! (Thanks to being awarded the 'Revival' badge.)